# Stripping out non-X12 characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, character, edi, x12

I didn't find this so I thought I would post it.  I needed a function to strip out disallowed characters in X12 fields.

Basic character set allowed:

Uppercase letters    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
Numeric digits       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Special characters   ! " & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; ? =
The space character

Control characters:  BEL HT  LF  VT  FF  CR  FS  GS  RS  US  NL
ASCII hex values:    07  09  0A  0B  0C  0D  1C  1D  1E  1F

Extended character set alowed:

Lowercase letters    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
Other special chars  % ~ @ [ ] _ { } \ | < >
National characters  # $

Control characters:  SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB
ASCII hex values:    01  02  03  04  05  06  11  12  13  14  15  16  17

Some times I want to allow only the Basic character set and some times I want to allow the extended character set depending on the file and the partner.  This is the code I came up with:

```
-- This function is for stripping out non-X12 characters 
-- with the option of also stripping out X12 extended characters
-- which are %~@[]_{}\|<>
/* 
Declare @text as nvarchar(max) = N'% ~ @ [ ] _ { } \ | < > A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z / { } *'  + char(27) + char(189) + char(191) + '* 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ! " & ( ) * + , - . / : ; ? = _ ^ %'
Print @text
Print [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text,'')
Print [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text,'~@_{}\|<>')
Print [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text,'[]~@_{}\|<>')
Print [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text,'[]~@_{}\|<>%^"')
Print [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text,'[]~@_{}\|<>%^-"*')
Print [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text,'[]~@_{}\|<>%^-"* ')
*/
CREATE Function [dbo].[f_remove_non_x12_chars_extended](@text VarChar(MAX), @extraChars varchar(100) = '')
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin
    -- PATINDEX treats the []%_^- charcters as wildcards so we have to treat them differently
    Declare @hasOpenBracket as bit = 0
    Declare @hasClosedBracket as bit = 0
    Declare @hasPercent as bit = 0
    Declare @hasUnderscore as bit = 0
    Declare @hasCaret as bit = 0
    Declare @hasDash as bit = 0

    -- If the wildcards are in the extra character set remove them from @extraCharacters and set a flag that they are in there
    if CHARINDEX('[', @extraChars) > 1  begin set @hasOpenBracket = 1;  set @extraChars = REPLACE(@extraChars, '[', '');    end
    if CHARINDEX(']', @extraChars) > 1  begin set @hasClosedBracket = 1;set @extraChars = REPLACE(@extraChars, ']', '');    end
    if CHARINDEX('%', @extraChars) > 1  begin set @hasPercent = 1;      set @extraChars = REPLACE(@extraChars, '%', '');    end
    if CHARINDEX('_', @extraChars) > 1  begin set @hasUnderscore = 1;   set @extraChars = REPLACE(@extraChars, '_', '');    end
    if CHARINDEX('^', @extraChars) > 1  begin set @hasCaret = 1;        set @extraChars = REPLACE(@extraChars, '^', '');    end
    if CHARINDEX('-', @extraChars) > 1  begin set @hasDash = 1;         set @extraChars = REPLACE(@extraChars, '-', '');    end

    Declare @removeValues as varchar(50) = '%[' + CHAR(0) + '-' + CHAR(31) + CHAR(127) + '-' + CHAR(255)  + @extraChars +  ']%'
    Declare @ptr int = PatIndex(@removeValues, @text COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)
    While @ptr > 0
    BEGIN
        Set @text = Stuff(@text, @ptr, 1, '')
        Set @ptr  = PatIndex(@removeValues, @text COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)
    END

    -- Remove the extra characters if the flag is set
    if @hasOpenBracket  = 1     begin set @text = replace(@text, '[', '') end
    if @hasClosedBracket = 1    begin set @text = replace(@text, ']', '') end
    if @hasPercent  = 1         begin set @text = replace(@text, '%', '') end
    if @hasUnderscore   = 1     begin set @text = replace(@text, '_', '') end
    if @hasCaret    = 1         begin set @text = replace(@text, '^', '') end
    if @hasDash = 1             begin set @text = replace(@text, '-', '') end

    Return @text
    --Return CONCAT(@hasOpenBracket, @hasClosedBracket, @hasPercent, @hasUnderscore, @hasCaret, @extraChars, @text)
End
```

Just a tip to save some others some time.  If you would like to suggest improvements feel free!  If you want to be condensending go else where.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: sql-server / mssql - tag updated

Comment: Probably easier to use regex expressions for the bulk of these e.g. using just the basic character set: select 'Ax123345!"£$%^&*()_"', regexp_replace('Ax123345!"£$%^&*()_"', '[^A-Z0-9 !"&\'()*+,-./:;?=]+');

Comment: You had me excited for a minute as I thought there was a regex search in ms-sql that I didn't know about!  Unfortunately ms-sql doesn't have a similar construct and the PATINDEX function is much less powerful with several weaknesses that have to be worked around.   I appreciate the suggestion but doesn't exist in my flavor of tsql.